# Using Excel.Application in ASP where Excel is installed on Client Machines instead of the Server

Tags: excel, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a server with an asp page on it that generates a report in Excel, using the Excel.Application object. Normally, Excel would have to be installed on the server to work. I was wondering, however, if it is possible to utilise the excel install on client machines to do this instead, as I can't install Excel on the server?

Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: It is very dangerous to call the Office Automation APIs from any server application, including an ASP Classic application. Those APIs are developed for use on a desktop machine, and will have unpredictable failures when running in a service environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you would need to fetch raw data into the users browser and use JavaScript to automate excel via its COM object model, this would be pretty horrific for a multitude of reasons, not least the security reconfiguration your users would have to perform on their machines.

YMMV but [ADO](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278973) can be used to create excel files.

Comment: OK so it seems that rewriting in ADO is a possibility... now to learn ADO...

Cheers :)